# New Tab function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I make chrome extension that collects links and opening them in new tab when clicking on them.
I made the first part that is collecting all the current URLs and this is the popup.js:

```
function GetUrls()
    {
    var fourmTabs = new Array();
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            fourmTabs[i] = tabs[i];
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < fourmTabs.length; i++) {
            if (fourmTabs[i] != null)
            {
            document.write("<b>" + fourmTabs[i].title + "</b>" + "<br/><a href='" + fourmTabs[i].url + "'>" + fourmTabs[i].url + "</a><br/><br/>");
             }  
            else {
                document.write("??" + i);
            }
        }
    });
    }
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", GetUrls());

    function OpenInNewTab(url )
    {
     var win=window.open(url, '_blank');
      win.focus();
    }
     //document.addEventListener('??', OpenInNewTab(??));
```

I try to use this OpenInNewTab() function but i cant send links from GetUrls() to it because these are local variables..any help in this point?
or there is better idea to open links i get in new tab??

This is popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Links Collector</title>
<style>
body {
  min-width:500px; 
overflow-x:hidden;
}
</style>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height: 150px; clear: both;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Links collector",
  "description": "This extension get urls you open and can save them.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ], 
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: Why not make them global?

Comment: @ZachSaucier I tried,but this lead me to repeat the for loops.Because the operations are in the GetUrls().
Any better idea?

Comment: But couldn't you make it global but clear it at the beginning of GetUrls?

Comment: @Gemy You are writing the links to a document and displaying as hyperlinks. Why do you even need the OpenInNewTab function? Just add target="_blank" to <a> tag and you don't even need any event listener. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: @ZachSaucier If you mean to move var fourmTabs = new Array(); from GetUrls().Nothing will happen,and get blank page in the new tab when clicking on the button not the links,i tried that.
or what do you mean?

Comment: @zambrey that is maybe what i need.I'll try it man.
Thank you.

Comment: @zambrey Can you show me how to write  target="_blank" at <a>in my code,please ?

Comment: I mean `var fourmTabs; function GetUrls() { fourmTabs = new Array(); ... }`. This way it is global but refreshes itself each time GetUrls runs

Comment: @ZachSaucier Thank you,I made it with target="_blank".
Happy new year.

Comment: @zambrey do you know how to save these links to bookmarks if i want ??

Comment: @Gemy Have you looked at this? http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html

Comment: @zambrey I read it,check the edit on the question please.

Comment: @Gemy You should add a new question instead of changing the original one as anyone visiting this question won't be able to make sense of que and the accepted answer without going through the history. Also you will get a much bigger audience for a new question.

Comment: @zambrey ok,by the way do you know the answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add target attribute to `<a>` as follows

```
document.write("<b>" + fourmTabs[i].title + "</b>" + "<br/><a href='" + fourmTabs[i].url + "' target='_blank'>" + fourmTabs[i].url + "</a><br/><br/>");
```

For more information check this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp out.